# Hibernate code generation does not create EJB3 annotation on export

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

Im trying to reverese engineer Mysql db into pojo java with annotation.

this is my configuration :

[image]

both "Use Java 5 syntax" and "Generate EJB3 annotations" are selected for export.

But the final export have no annotation in it.

[image]

In other hand i can achieve this by selecting multiple class from explorer , right click

and select "source/Generate Hibernate/jpa annotation" , but its kinda messy.(most fields

does not get any columns annotation)".

[image]

Or should i set something in "hibernate.reveng.xml" ? like adding Tables & Columns

explicity in here :

[image]

Or it should find out all of schema definition by it self and add it as a annotation to

class?

Answer (score 1):

In your hibernate configuration,choose Hibernate Version 4.3

Comment: this worked for me, wonder why : /